# Ошибка setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь зациклить выполнение функции JavaScript. Но получаю ошибку -

**Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined at :1:1.**

Что сделал не так?

```js
function test() {
  console.log('test_');
  setTimeout('test()', 1000);
}
test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код находится внутри другой функции. Из-за этого функция `test` не видна в глобальной области видимости.

```js
   
function starter() {
  function test() {
    console.log('test_');
    setTimeout('test()', 1000);
  }
  test();
}
starter();
```

Без обертки это работает:

```js
   
  function test() {
    console.log('test_');
    setTimeout('test()', 1000);
  }
  test();
```

Поэтому лучше подавать в `setTimeout` не строку кода, а ссылку на функцию. Это работает независимо от наличия/отсутствия обертки:

```js
function starter() {
  function test() {
    console.log('test_');
    setTimeout(test, 1000);
  }
  test();
}
starter();
```

Comment: Понял теперь ошибку. Спасибо))

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` принимает в качестве аргументов функцию и время. Вы передали строку. Нужно вот так

```js
function test() {
    console.log('test_');
  setTimeout(test, 1000);
}
test();
```

Comment: Строку тоже можно передавать. Но она выполняется в глобальной области видимости.